# Adding space between fragments with one layout in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `FrameLayout` defined as the following:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

I have a method that can add multiple fragments to this layout as follows:

```
private void setView(Fragment... fragments) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    for (Fragment f : fragments) {
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();
    }
}
```

All my fragments get rendered on the UI but they are on top of each other, how can I make them horizontally aligned with space between them?

Comment: I think you can do that with viewpager

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options that might work for this.  First option is to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to have the fragments shown in a paged horizontal component.  The second, if you know beforehand the amount of fragments that will be added, is to use multiple frame layout containers and add the fragments to those containers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to replace FrameLayout with LinearLayout, or use a LinearLayout as a child of FrameLayout

```
    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

and second,

```
    private void setView(Fragment... fragments) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        for (Fragment f : fragments) {
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f, "unique_string_for_each_fragment");
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

If you don't provide the unique id for each `add()` operation, then it overlays each fragment on top of the other.

Hope this helps!

CR.